# What is the difference between primary and secondary user stores?

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I don't see anyone asking this question or it being in documentation, but what are the differences between defining a user store as primary or secondary and what advantage does one have over another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the users in primary userstore, you can simply use their username. (eg. userX) But, for the users in secondary userstores, you have to use `domain/username` to identify them. (eg. domainX/userY)

When you have multiple userstores, you can have only 1 primary one, and rest should be secondary. There are no advantages or disadvantages as such.

If you don't have multiple userstores, you can simply go with the primary one.

Comment: I see. I also noticed LDAP read-only stores that are set as primary don't work well within WSO2. It might be helpful in future documentation to specify that only 1 primary store can be defined at a given time and additional user stores must be secondary.

Comment: 1) This explains how to configure a readonly primary userstore. https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+a+Read-only+LDAP+User+Store 
2) I believe primary/secondary usage is covered in https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+User+Stores

Comment: I see. It's still difficult though to gauge the actual number of primary stores allowed from the singular and plural tenses. There's "The Primary User Store" and "Primary User Stores". Hard to differentiate.